# panic! does not stop an Iron server

Tags: rust, iron

I thought `panic!` stops everything in Rust, but if I `panic!` in an Iron route handler function it does not stop the whole server. Instead, it just displays the panic message.

Is it the "normal" behavior of `panic!`?

I'm not posting my actual code because I don't think it's useful here, but I can add it if required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought `panic!` stops everything in Rust.

Not quite: `panic!` only stops¹ the *current* thread, which for single threaded programs stops the whole program. If you spawn another thread, the parent thread can detect whether or not the child thread panicked [on joining](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join).

Iron uses many threads to handle multiple requests in parallel. Apparently it just ignores panics in child threads...

---

¹ As DK. and Vladimir Matveev mentioned in the comments, it's not *that* simple. Multiple things can happen when a panic is "thrown". By default, the application starts unwinding (climbing down the stack) until "the end" of the stack or a `catch_unwind` is reached. In the former case, the thread is killed; in the latter it's up to the user to decide what happens. It's also [possible to configure](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32900) your build such that `abort` is called on `panic!`.

Comment: `panic!` doesn't necessarily *stop* the current thread.  By default, it begins unwinding which will continue it *either* terminates the thread *or* it unwinds into a `catch_unwind` call.  Alternately, it could just abort the whole process.

Comment: Note that it is possible to enable abort on panic in the latest Rust versions.

Answer (score 2):

`panic!` in Rust is akin to exceptions in other languages, with two major differences:

- you cannot specify a "type"
- you cannot specify "data"

This makes it awkward to use it for out-of-bands signalling, and therefore reserves its use to "Oops" situations.

Otherwise, it behaves much in the same way in general: the current thread of execution unwinds (calling destructors as appropriate) until one of 3 things happen:

- a destructor `panic!`: the process aborts immediately
- the bottom of the stack is reached: the process aborts immediately
- a `catch_unwind` is reached: the handler decides what to do

Along the way, the various destructors might *poison* some multi-thread data structures, which may cause other threads to panic when they attempt to use them, etc... that is however a library decision and is not enforced by the language itself.

*Note: as noted by others, there is now another behavior for panics, immediate abortion. It shaves off some code, and obviously prevents graceful recovery.*